# unable to set value in text box for responsive website creation

Tags: php, android, html, codeigniter

i am working in php application using codeigniter framework. it is a web application with responsive website design. currently there is no separate app for the site.

In my application in view page i am trying to set the value in text box as follows:

```
<input type="text" value="mg/dl" name="name_T3_unit_edit" id="T3_unit_edit" autocomplete="off">
```

when i open site in Desktop/Laptop it shows the value "mg/dl" but when i open the website on mobile in chrome browser it doesn't set the the value "mg/dl".

when i submit the form using desktop/laptop, it sets the value to DB but when i use mobile it sets 0 value.

i am using POST method for submitting the value to controller. i am not getting what is the difference when i use mobile and desktop/laptop and what property i am missing to set value for mobile view.

i have tried `data-mini="true"` but didn't work for me.

please give me suggestions to overcome with this problem.

Comment: by itself it looks ok on mobile chrome -- https://jsfiddle.net/zqjaj4y5/ -- some other code you have is probably the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have same block of code two times in view page HTML, one displayed at desktop view port another for mobile view port. may be you missed to set the value to the input text for mobile view port.

Comment: Thanks for answering. i found a mistake in css part which reset the value of text field therefore it was not showing the value for mobile view.

Answer (score 1):

through javascript try

```
document.getElementById("myText").defaultValue = "Goofy";
```

on page load